# +ve & -ve vs 5v and GND

Tags: wiring, polarity

I am learning hardware form a software background (playing with Arduino) and I am having difficulty remembering absolute wiring basics.

Bu board has a 5v and gnd pin, whilst my component has + & - terminals; which way round do I connect these?

Thanks

Comment: It's +5V and GND. So the + terminal goes to +5 and the - terminal goes to GND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+5 with +,
and
GND with -

So simple.